# Android launch activity on the top of the password

Tags: android

Question : How to be able on android to trigger an intent on the top of the locked screen ?

Behaviour wanted : pending intent is triggered while phone was asleep, phone wake and launch activity, user closes activity and has now the "enter your password" screen if there is one.

Example : Android standart alarm/clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the accurate answer :

To wake up the phone :

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
    wakeLock.acquire();
```

To launch the activity on the top of the password :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking for something that is part of android, try grepcode :

google://alarm clock grepcode

gives :
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/1.5_r4/com/android/alarmclock/AlarmReceiver.java